# Edit app:mcv_calendarDiff in material-hijri-calendarview library

Tags: java, calendar

I created a AlertDialog that displays the Hijri calendar
From this library:
  [material-hijri-calendarview](https://github.com/eltohamy/material-hijri-calendarview)
In the calendar layout there is a line: app:mcv_calendarDiff="0" If I Edit the value, the month will be advanced or delayed in the calendar according to the value.
**Problem:** I did not find a programmatic way to change the value of :app:mcv_calendarDiff to use the value in savedCorrectionValue that the user chooses

**xml:**

```
<com.github.eltohamy.materialhijricalendarview.MaterialHijriCalendarView
                android:id="@+id/calendarView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layoutDirection="ltr"
                app:mcv_calendarDiff="0"
                app:mcv_dateTextAppearance="@style/CustomDayTextAppearance"
                app:mcv_headerTextAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                app:mcv_selectionColor="#00796B"
                app:mcv_tileSize="42dp"
                app:mcv_showOtherDates="all"
                app:mcv_weekDayTextAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
```

**Code:**

```
   private MaterialHijriCalendarView calendarView;
   private void calendar() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.dialog_hijri_calendar, null);
        builder.setView(view);
        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();

    SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE); 
    int savedCorrectionValue = preferences.getInt("correctionValue", 0);


    calendarView = view.findViewById(R.id.calendarView);

    if (savedCorrectionValue != 0 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, savedCorrectionValue);
        Date newDate = calendar.getTime();

        CalendarDay newCalendarDay = CalendarDay.from(newDate);
        calendarView.setDateSelected(newCalendarDay, true);
        
        calendarView.setCurrentDate(newDate);

        calendarView.invalidateDecorators(); 
    }else {
     
        calendarView.setSelectedDate(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());


    }


    alertDialog.show();
 }
```

Inside the library class on line 247 there is a mcv_calendarDiff definition that is:

```
         calendarDiff = a.getInteger(R.styleable.MaterialHijriCalendarView_mcv_calendarDiff, 0);
```

Whereas, if there is no value entered in mcv_calendarDiff, the default value of 0 is used.

this is the [class MaterialHijriCalendarView](https://github.com/eltohamy/material-hijricalendarview/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/github/eltohamy/materialhijricalendarview/MaterialHijriCalendarView.java):

I hope you can help please